# Javascript Regex to match numbers 1 to 11 only

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I need to create a regex in Javascript (NOT JQUERY).

The regex must match numbers from 1 to 11 only.

I started with this regex to allow numbers 1 to 11 but it also allows 21, 31, 41, 51, etc. I jsut need numbers 1 to 11. Thank you.

```
var range = /([0-9][0-1]{1,2})/g;
```

Clarification: I need to use a regex for form validation. I am using the HTML attribute "min/max" but the platform I am working in still submits the form, so I need to catch it on the client side before submitting to the server.

Comment: Try `^(1[01]|[1-9])$`.

Comment: Why use a regex at all?

Comment: There is an old saying, a developer had a problem, he though he would solve with regex.  Now he has two problems

Comment: `n => n>=1 && n<=11` is best regex

Comment: @vp_arth how can you do that client side? linqjs?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions

Comment: @vp_arth my mind is blown I test this out somewhere

Comment: @vp_arth how do you use that with regex? or do you use some other function for the filter?

Comment: @johnny5, it should be used **instead** of regex. Or even `<input type="number" min="1" max="11" step="1" required />`

Comment: Thanks I'm so stoked for js lambdas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the regex, assuming that the text can contain only this number, and nothing else: `/^([1-9]|1[01])$/`

You can play with this [here](https://regex101.com/r/fI7kH0/1).

Explanation:

- `/^...$/` makes sure that it matches from start to end. So `12` won't match just because the starting `1`.
- The alternative `(...|...)` allows two kind of numbers:

  - `[1-9]` allows one digit numbers from 1 to 9.
  - `1[01]` allows two digit numbers starting with 1, then comes 0 or 1.

Comment: You can't remove the anchors altogether, though. That would match any number, like `111`. You'd at least need to check for word boundary - `/\b([1-9]|1[01])\b/`.

Answer (score 1):

I was completely over-complicating this. All I need to do is check if it is an integer and throw and error if not, then check if the int < 1 || int > 11.

Thank you for all of the suggestions.